# Java Spring persist stack trace when 500 error happens

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am hosting an Spring boot application on Amazon EC2. Sometimes in the morning when I go to the webpage I will see

"Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begin transaction failed:"

from the browser. However I have no way to get back the stack trace. So is this possible in Spring: When 500 error happens, spring will catch the exception and store it in database or local file so I can get it back later. I think it would be helpful for debug the hard-to-reproduce 500 errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible you just need configure your controllers to use Spring exception handling https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc

Then you can configure which level of exceptions you want to catch(in your case general Exception would be ok, or if you know the specific exception much better)

```
    // Total control - setup a model and return the view name yourself. Or consider
    // subclassing ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver (see below).
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
     public ModelAndView handleError(HttpServletRequest req, Exception exception) {
       logger.error("Request: " + req.getRequestURL() + " raised " + exception);
       //Here you can persist the exception or just write in the log
       ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
       mav.addObject("exception", exception);
       mav.addObject("url", req.getRequestURL());
       mav.setViewName("error");
       return mav;
     }
   }
```